# Trouble with while True and if statements.

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble trying to get out of a loop. Here is part of the code:

```
def save():
    newFileName = raw_input("Please enter a name for your save file")
    saveFile = open(newFileName+".txt" , "w")
    saveFile.write(str(guessesRemaining) + "\n" + str(npegs) + "\n" + str(numberColours) + "\n" + str(coloursUsed) + "\n" + str(code))
    print "Game saved."


def validateInput():

    inputGuess = raw_input("Please enter your guess as letters: ")

    while True:
        if inputGuess == "save":
            save()
            validateInput()


        elif len(inputGuess) != npegs:
            inputGuess = raw_input("Please enter the same number of letters as pegs you chose to play with: ")
        else:

            wordList = list(inputGuess.upper())

            invalidLetters = False
            for letter in wordList:
                if letter not in coloursUsed:
                    invalidLetters = True

            if invalidLetters == True:
                print "Possible colours are", coloursUsed

            else:
                return wordList
```

Basically it's a mastermind game, that can be saved by storing some data inside a text file. To save, you just type "save" in and it runs the save function. The problem is, once I've chosen a file name and it saves, I want to be able to keep playing the game. However, once it's saved it runs the:

```
inputGuess = raw_input("Please enter your guess as letters"
```

as I get prompted to enter letters, but no matter what I enter it just asks me to chose a name for a save file and then it saves again. How can I fix it so I can carry on playing.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should not use recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basing on an infinite recursion during the game. Also your validation is wrong. The best thing to do for such a messed-up code is to try to partition it, something like this:

```
def takeAGuess(inputGuess):
    wordList = list(inputGuess.upper())

    invalidLetters = False
    for letter in wordList:
        if letter not in coloursUsed:
            invalidLetters = True

    if invalidLetters == True:
        print "Possible colours are", coloursUsed
        return None
    else:
        return wordList

def validateInput():
    inputGuess = raw_input("Please enter your guess as letters: ")

    if inputGuess == "save":
        save()
        return None
    elif len(inputGuess) != npegs:
        inputGuess = raw_input("Please enter the same number of letters as pegs you chose to play with: ")
        return takeAGuess(inputGuess)
    else:
        return takeAGuess(inputGuess)

while True:
    result = validateInput()
    # result is either None to continue playing, or a wordList
    # not sure what do you want to do with it
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I've got more code than just what I posted, when I make the changes you suggested it kind of breaks everything.

Comment: @JaAnTr Nevertheless it needs to be partitioned, and recursion is the wrong way to go.